# How to connect to mscrm using username and password?

Tags: authentication, dynamics-crm, credentials

How can I replace and extend this code to use password and username in authentication credentials. I was trying to solve this by analyzing examples in mscrm sdk but without luck since I`m not c# programmer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void id_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();

        //Authenticate using credentials of the logged in user;       
        ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();


        Uri OrganizationUri = new Uri("http://Crm/Contoso/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");
        Uri HomeRealmUri = null;

        //OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy;       
        using (OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, HomeRealmUri, Credentials, null))
        {
            IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)serviceProxy;

            //Instantiate the contact object and populate the attributes.
            Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
            contact["firstname"] = txtFirstName.Text.ToString();
            contact["lastname"] = txtLastName.Text.ToString();
            Guid newContactId = service.Create(contact);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you are using Active Directory authentication here. There is a rather long winded example on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675404.aspx) which shows how to create a connection for all authentication methods.

I believe you only have to change:

```
ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();
```

To:

```
ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();
Credentials.UserName.UserName = "domain\username";
Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using default credentials if at all possible, if not possible then we use something like this:

```
ClientCredentials creds = new ClientCredentials();
creds.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain"]);
```

Obvious downside of this method is that the password is in cleartext, but the upside is that you don't need to recompile to change password or user.